# Is it possible to identify new added files in PR on teamcity?

Tags: github, teamcity

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:
A PR on Github triggers a build on TeamCity. This PR has some new added files. I want to pass names of these files to my script that is used in the build steps through configuration/environment parameters.

Is this possible?

I would appreciate any ideas how to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity doesn't have a native concept of what a GitHub pull request is, so you'll need to use `git` to generate the list of new files yourself. If you know that the merge base of the pull request is the same for all builds in the configuration, let's say `master` as an example, then you can do it with a `git` one-liner without involving GitHub at all:

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A master...`

If you don't know the merge base of the pull request, you'll need to first query GitHub's API for it:

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/pulls/${PR_NUMBER} | jq '.base.ref'`

and pass the result of that into the `git diff` command instead of just using `master`.